# Software install failure

Tags: downloads

I am getting a "Package Operations Failed" message at the 95% mark of each download.

Details show "Reading database" for each 5 percentage segment until

```
Reading database ... 95%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error 
aborting: failed in buffer_read(fd): files list for package `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly'
```

I have tried to download a number of piece of software (most recently PDF Editor) and am getting the same message at the same point in the download.

Is there something wrong with my Ubuntu version, a virus or is it the software being downloaded?  Using 10.04 LTS.

P.S. Same problem when trying to download updates.

---

Mik . . . thanks for the feedback . . . should start by letting you know that I'm a recycled Windows user so have very limit knowledge using the terminal window . . . hate MS, Google, Facebook and all the other commercial info harvesters and converted to open source sofeware and WYSIWYG Ubuntu two years ago . . . having said that here's what happened when I ran `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
primary@primary-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
primary@primary-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-21
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
primary@primary-desktop:~$ apt - get autoremove
The program 'apt' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
primary@primary-desktop:~$ openjdk-6-jdk
openjdk-6-jdk: command not found
primary@primary-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install pdfedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-21
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt3-mt
Suggested packages:
  libqt3-mt-psql libqt3-mt-mysql libqt3-mt-odbc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt3-mt pdfedit
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/5,380kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.4MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously deselected package libqt3-mt.
(Reading database ... 95%
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 failed in buffer_read(fd): files list for package `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
primary@primary-desktop:~$
```

Still see fatal error message at 95% "reading database" mark . . . appreciate further feedback . . .

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Answer (score 1):

First type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

Try again to install your software.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue to this at the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1426933); I don't think any `apt-get` or `dpkg` fixes will work until the `gstreamer` problem has been fixed.

What you could do is rename the offending list so it is not read by `dpkg`:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly.list.old
```

If you have any more stuck packages this method should work for them too- just **replace** gstreamer with another package name; at least a similar fix worked [at the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9935164&postcount=25) for various packages.

You should now be able to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and you can install anything you require or even **reinstall** the gstreamer plugins if you wish and a fresh list file for them will be downloaded.